# How do I simulate user input in debug mode?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When switching to a line with user input, the variable that should store it is not initialized in the "variables" tab, which is probably logical, but I don't understand why.How do I simulate user input in debug mode?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYb7u.png)

Comment: There should be a console tab you can switch to. It will allow you to enter text just like when running the program normally.

Comment: It's work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Console tab is enabled for the debugger tool window layout. If you can't see it, try restoring the default layout:

[image: Debugger layout]

You can also Drag & Drop the console tab to the bottom of the tool window so that it's visible at the same time:

[image: Constole at the bottom]

Focus the Console tab and type what you need.